# Trace entropies

Tags: real-analysis, differential-equations, it.information-theory, entropy, differential-inequalities

I'm studying relationships between trace entropy functionals and combinatorics and I'm faced with the following problem. Lets $\mathcal {D}$ be the following differential operator $1 -x\cdot \cfrac{d}{dx}$ i.e. $\mathcal {D} g = g - x\cdot g'$.

For $m\ge 0$ integer, if $\Phi_m(x) := x\cdot \log(x)^m$ then $\mathcal {D} \Phi_m(x) = -m\cdot \Phi_{m-1}(x)$ and, (at least formally) for a function $g$ we can write
$g(x) = \sum\limits_{m\ge 0} g_m \cdot \Phi_m(x)$ where $$g_m = \cfrac{(-1)^m}{m!}\cdot \mathcal {D}^m g(x) |_{x=1}\;.$$

I am trying to figure out what kind of functions $g(x)$ can satisfy the following conditions on $(0;1]$

I) $g(x) \ge 0$, $g(0)=0$.  (Positivity)

II) $\mathcal {D}^2 g(x) \le 0$. (some sort of $\mathcal {D}$-concavity)

III) $\left(\mathcal {D}^2 - \mathcal {D}\right) g(x) \le 0$   (this is standard concavity expressed with the operator $\mathcal {D}$

IV) $\exists \ 0< \varepsilon \le 1$ such that $g(x) > -x^2\cdot \log(x) \quad \forall \ x \in (0;\varepsilon)$

V) $\exists \ a \in (0;\frac{1}{2}]$ such that $$g(a)+g(1-a) = -a\cdot \log(a) -(1-a)\cdot \log(1-a).$$

If we impose only conditions I),II) and III) there are a lot of functions satisfying them, but

1. adding IV) I'm not able to find any function except of the following form  $g(x) = k\cdot x \cdot \log(x), \ k$ real constant (here $\varepsilon=1$). Note that $g$ do not satisfy V).
2. adding IV) and V) I'm not able to find any other function except the Boltzman-Gibbs-Shannon entropy trace :  $-x\cdot \log(x)$

I "fear" that the Boltzman-Gibbs-Shannon entropy trace is the unique function satisfying I)-V).

Thanks in advance for any point of view.

Comment: When you spell out "$\exists\ 0< \varepsilon\le1$", you will get "there exists the double inequality $0< \varepsilon\le1$". In fact, this double inequality always exists, at least in some sense, and it may or may not be satisfied. Clearly, you wanted to say "$\exists\ \varepsilon\in(0,1]$" instead.

Comment: @IosifPinelis you've just created the tag [tag:differential-inequalities]; would you create a tag excerpt as well?

Comment: @YCor : I have done that -- my first tag excerpt. Do you have any comments on it?

Comment: Looks OK, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $c\in(0,\log2]$, the function $g$ defined by the formula $g(x)=cx$ for $x\in[0,1]$ satisfies your conditions I)–V), but it is not the Boltzman–Gibbs–Shannon entropy trace.

---

There are many more functions $g$ satisfying your conditions I)–V) that are not the Boltzman–Gibbs–Shannon entropy trace. In particular, for any $c_1\in(0,\log2)$, any nonnegative continuous function $H$ on $[0,1]$, and any small enough real $c_2\ge0$ and $c_3\ge0$, the function $g$ defined by the formula
$$g(x)=c_1x-c_2 x\log x-c_3 x\int_0^x du\,H(u)\log\frac xu$$
for $x\in[0,1]$ satisfies your conditions I)–V), but it is not the
Boltzmann–Gibbs–Shannon entropy trace.

Comment: @YCor : Thank you for editing the m-dashes. How do you make them? (One n-dash remains, though, in place of an m-dash.)

Comment: You can produce them by copy-paste now. On my Mac I'm using shift + ⌥ ("option") + dash to get the medium dash –. Using only shift + dash makes a longer dash —.

Comment: Hi Iosif,
 Thanks a lot for your detailed and quick answer. I have been very surprised that I didn't saw at least the solution $k\cdot x$. I realized that I did a little mistake in my conditions, the conditon IV) is $g(x) > -x\cdot log(x)$ (there is no square). The $k\cdot x$ is then not ok but the second set of functions work very well.
 
 Thanks again

Comment: @Gianfranco : So, if you are satisfied with this answer, can we have it marked respectively? https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers https://mathoverflow.net/help/accepted-answer